# Caching return value from a service method

Tags: node.js, typescript, caching, service, nestjs

I am using nestjs and have just installed the `cache-manager` module and are trying to cache a response from a service call.

I register the cache module in a sample module (sample.module.ts):

```
import { CacheInterceptor, CacheModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SampleService } from './sample.service';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';


@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register({
      ttl: 10,
      store: redisStore,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379,
    }),
 ],
 providers: [
   SampleService,
   {
     provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
     useClass: CacheInterceptor,
   }
 ],
 exports: [SampleService],
})
export class SampleModule {}
```

Then in my service (sample.service.ts):

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
  @UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
  @CacheKey('findAll')
  async findAll() {
    // Make external API call
  }
}
```

Looking at redis I can see that nothing is cached for the service method call. If I use the same approach with a controller, then everything works fine and I can see the cached entry in my redis database. I am thinking that there is no way out of the box to cache individual service method calls in nestjs.

Reading the [`documentation`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching) it seems that I am only able to use this approach for controllers, microservices and websockets, but not ordinary services?

Comment: I ended up writing a small decorator that can be used to handle caching for services: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cyclonecode/service-cache

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct, it is **not possible** to use the cache the same way for services as for controllers.

This is because the magic happens in the [`CacheInterceptor`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/41764370eb38593ea6b276ae0f34b911a000e05f/packages/common/cache/interceptors/cache.interceptor.ts#L47) and `Interceptors` can only be used in `Controllers`.

---

However, you can inject the `cacheManager` into your service and use it directly:

```
export class SampleService {

  constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) protected readonly cacheManager) {}  

  findAll() {
    const value = await this.cacheManager.get(key)
    if (value) {
      return value
    }

    const respone = // ...
    this.cacheManager.set(key, response, ttl)
    return response
  }
```

Comment: Yes I also figured out this is the way, I had problems with my method running multiple times before the cache was actually set though, but this was not really a problem related to caching.